# How to get rid of Index Out of Bounds Exception error while removing a row from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I understand that how the error is being caused as there seems to be a problem with array indexing after removal of a row at random ,so how do go around to fix it.Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my Code

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<String> reminderMessage;
private ArrayList<String> receiverName;

public DataAdapter(ArrayList<String> reminderMessage,ArrayList<String> receiverName) {

    this.reminderMessage = reminderMessage;
    this.receiverName = receiverName;
}

@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cards_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    viewHolder.reminderText.setText(reminderMessage.get(i));
    viewHolder.receiverName.setText(receiverName.get(i));
    viewHolder.button_reject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            rejectItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return reminderMessage.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView reminderText;
    private TextView receiverName;
    Button button_reject;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        reminderText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.remindertext);
        receiverName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.receiverName);
        button_reject=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_reject);
    }
}

private void rejectItem(int position) {

    DatabaseReference mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    try {

        mdatabase.child("reminders").child(messageKeys.get(position)).child("status").setValue("reject");
        Log.d("in the loop","writing");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    reminderMessage.remove(position);
    receiverName.remove(position);
    messageKeys.remove(position);

    notifyItemRemoved(position);

    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, reminderMessage.size());

     }
   }
```

And here is the error

```
 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.admin.import2, PID: 6891
                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                      at com.example.admin.import2.DataAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.java:47)
                      at com.example.admin.import2.DataAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.java:27)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6279)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6312)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5258)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5521)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5363)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5359)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2141)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1525)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1488)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:585)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3506)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2969)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1658)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.import2-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.admin.import2-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use one list of some object like this?

```
class Data{
    String name, message;
}
```

Plus

```
public DataAdapter(List<Data> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

By using two lists, you are only using the size of one, while removing and getting from both, which only causes errors later  on

Besides that, `messageKeys` is not defined in the question, so please debug that too

If you want to use Firebase, give [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) a chance